# How do you save a input on tkinter as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to get a tkinter window to ask for a team name then to save it as a variable, this is what I have so far...

```python
import tkinter

def new_game_func():
    def save():
        print('Saving team')
        print(E1)
    team=0
    while team<=4:
        team=team+1
        newgamew=tkinter.Tk()
        label1 = tkinter.Label(newgamew, text="Team name:")
        E1 = tkinter.Entry(newgamew, bd =5)
        submit = tkinter.Button(newgamew, text ="Submit", command=save)
        label1.pack()
        E1.pack()
        submit.pack()
        newgamew.mainloop()
    team()

new_game_func()
```

All it displays is:

```
Saving team
.20237872
```

How would I save it as plain text and not a bunch of numbers?!?!

Comment: You should work through a tkinter tutorial and/or read some documentation before asking such a fundamental question.  This question shows absolutely no signs of research or attempts to solve the problem before asking.

Comment: Well @BryanOakley I am currently a student learning python, I'm trying to learn as much as I can at the moment and I just wanted to finish this project so I have experience of using tkinter before doing the tutorial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`E1` is the reference for your `Entry`. If you wish to access the text within the `Entry`, you can use `E1.get()`.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help @SolarFactories how would I use `E1.get()` in my code, where would I put it?

Comment: Where you currently have `print(E1)`, you can insert `teamName=E1.get()`

Comment: wow thank you so much @SolarFactories for your help, I haven't been doing python and tkinter for long and I'm going to start a tkinter tutorial asap ! :-)